# Google Apps Script Chart Services: The script completed but did not return anything?

Tags: google-apps-script

Main question: why is the script below not returning anything? When given a version and deployed, the script returns 'The script completed but did not return anything.'

(Bonus question: can I run two charts on two different datatables within the same dashboard and within the same script?)

The input is a Google Spreadsheet with four columns and a header row: Year|Month|Group|Count, all numerics except Group (single letter).

The objective is to create a line chart of total counts by yearmo (201001, 201002...). Ideally I'd like to generate another line chart of total counts by year-group within the same script, but one step at a time...

Since the data isn't rolled up (and I'm new to google apps script and can't find any aggregation outside pivoting the spreadsheet itself), I resort to hashes to sum counts over year-month. I'll do the same for year-groups.

It may not be elegant (I happen to be new to js too), but it makes sense to me. Too bad it doesn't work. Thanks for pointers.

EDIT 2013-04-25

Tried to get too much done in a single script and lost my footing. So I've taken the aggregation outside of the script, created a new spreadsheet, and ran the code found here https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/chart-services/line-chart: got my line chart.

```
function doGet(){
  // counts by yearmo
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Atd6tVDA1d3UOI-jfkdlRHbk85Y19BcU9BNFdPNXBlVlE');
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var yr = [];
  var mo = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    yr[data[i][0]] = 0;
    mo[data[i][1]] = 0;
  }
  Logger.log( yrLvls = Object.keys(yr) );
  Logger.log( moLvls = Object.keys(mo) );
  // initialize hash
  var yearmo = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < yrLvls.length; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < moLvls.length; j++){
      var key = yrLvls[i] + '-' + moLvls[j]
      yearmo[ key ] = 0;
    }
  }
  // aggregation
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    yearmo[  data[i][0] + '-' + data[i][1] ]  +=  data[i][3];
  }
  // check
  var values = Object.keys(yearmo).map(function(key){
    return yearmo[key];
  });
  Logger.log( values );
  // Year Mo
  Logger.log( "--------------" );
  var data_yearmo = Charts.newDataTable()
  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, 'YearMo')
  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Count');
  Logger.log( Object.keys(yearmo) );
  for ( key in Object.keys(yearmo) ) {
      Logger.log( key );
      data_yearmo.addRow(  [ key , yearmo[key] ]  );
  }
  data_yearmo.build()

  var lineChart_yearmo = Charts.newLineChart()
   .setTitle('Counts')
   .setXAxisTitle('YearMo')
   .setYAxisTitle('Counts')
   .setCurveStyle(Charts.CurveStyle.SMOOTH)
   .setPointStyle(Charts.PointStyle.MEDIUM)
   .setDataTable(data_yearmo);

  var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Yearmo');
  uiApp.add(lineChart_yearmo);
  return uiApp;
}
```

Comment: does this really have anything to do with appengine ?

Comment: I'm still confused with Google's scripting offerings. Took the tag off.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you did not update the version of the app that you deployed. Try using the "latest code" development link (you can get it from the dialog when you deploy your app) and if that works, create a new version from the Manage Versions menu and update the deployed app to use that version.

Comment: I've saved and given the project a new version, then tried "latest code" (deploy app): same error.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add `.build()` to my `Charts.newLineChart()` call.

The `data_yearmo.build()` isn't necessary apparently, but the '.build()' for `Charts.newLineChart()` definitely is. Credit goes to the link in the Edit above.